# A robot moves any 4 direction up,down,left,right with specific number between 1-9

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a problem fixing this regex.

Problem: Assuming, the robot can move in any one of the four directions (Forward (F), Back (B), Left (L), Right (R)) followed by the number of steps it can move in that direction. The number of steps it can take is between 1 to 9.

Valid operations: F4L1B3, R5F2, B7, L8F2R4B3, L1, R5

Invalid operations: 12, LR, L2J2, K3F5, R12, F6L7R12, B5R8L+, L4-R3

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class extra {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        String move = scn.nextLine();
        finalPosition(move);
    }

    static void finalPosition(String move)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([F][1-9]+)|([B][1-9]+)|([L][1-9]+)|([R][1-9])") ;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(move);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        if (b)
        {
            System.out.println("Robot is moving");
        }else
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `(?<!\S)(?:[FBLR][1-9])+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/EiV2jh/1

Comment: [no white spaces](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd6rbz6r): `(?:[FBLR][1-9])+` // optional white spaces (between moves only): `(?:\s*[FBLR][1-9])+\s`  -  used with `Matcher#matches()`

Comment: in your regex there is `[1-9]+` which allows more than one digit. The `+` is probably meant to be outside the parenthesis (and missing at all for last alternative), but you must allow the whole to be repeated `(([F][1-9])|([B][1-9])|([L][1-9])|([R][1-9]))+` (almost the same as my first suggestion above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 uppercase character valid and all 4 can they be followed by a digit 1-9. This seems only to be valid in a sequence of 1 or more occurrences, without any other non whitespace characters are allowed to be part of the string.

You might shorted the whole alternation to a character class matching 1 of the 4 allowed characters followed by a digit 1-9 and repeat that as a whole 1 or more times.

To not let other characters be part of the match, you can use whitespace boundaries at the left and the right.

```
(?<!\S)(?:[FBLR][1-9])+(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert not a non whitspace char directly to the left
- `(?:[FBLR][1-9])+` Repeat 1 or more times matching either F B L R and a digit 1-9
- `(?!\S)` Assert not a non whitspace char directly to the left

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EiV2jh/1/)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)(?:[FBLR][1-9])+(?!\\S)";
```

If this is the only input that should match from the start till the end of the string, you might also use anchors:

```
^(?:[FBLR][1-9])+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2vkMl3/1)

Comment: Thanks brother it's helped me alot

Comment: Note: if using `Matcher#matches()`, as in code from question, there is no need for `^`  or  `$` , neither negative look-forward or -behind (and I believe regex101 is not 100% Java, but almost)